# CSS: Position loading indicator in the center of the screen

Tags: css, position, center

How can I position my loading indicator in the center of the screen. Currently I'm using a little placeholder and it seems to work fine. However, when I scroll down, the loading indicator stays right in that predefined position. How can I make it follow the scrolling so that it always sits on top??

```
#busy
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 35%;
    display: none;
    background: transparent url("../images/loading-big.gif");
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;
}

#busy-holder
{
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;        
}
```

Comment: I am not sure as to your problem. Maybe position: fixed. The HTML will help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`

The first one is relative to your screen window. (not affected by scrolling)

The second one is relative to the page. (affected by scrolling)

*Note* : IE6 doesn't support position:fixed.

Comment: @Kraz: the next question is, how to do that in the center of specific div, according to current viewport: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762818/how-to-center-image-in-the-specific-div-according-to-current-viewport-position

Comment: afaik, it's currently not doable in CSS only. Would require `position:absolute` (`fixed` won't work) and others values (top,right...) determined with javascript.

Answer (score 60):

```css
.loader{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Phi_fenomeni.gif/50px-Phi_fenomeni.gif') 
              50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Comment: How can I add the text too in center

Comment: Why did you add `rgb(249,249,249)`? That makes the spinner area opaque (white) rather than transparent. You need to remove that; most spinners are transparent, or semi-transparent at least (with an opacity of e.g. 0.3 or 0.4), but not opaque.

Comment: you can also do that

Answer (score 26):

This is what I've done for Angular 4:

```
<style type="text/css">  
  .centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:darkred;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root>
        <div class="centered">
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using an overlay that inhibits along with material design spinner that you configure one time in your app and you can call it from anywhere.

### app.component.html

(put this somewhere at the root level of your html)

```
<div class="overlay" [style.height.px]="height" [style.width.px]="width" *ngIf="message.plzWait$ | async">
        <mat-spinner class="plzWait"  mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

### app.component.css

```
.plzWait{
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top:50%;

}
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

### app.component.ts

```
height = 0;
width = 0;
constructor(
    private message: MessagingService
  }
ngOnInit() {
    this.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    this.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  }
```

### messaging.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
export class MessagingService {
    // Observable string sources
  private plzWaitObservable = new Subject<boolean>();


  // Public Observables you subscribe to
  public plzWait$ = this.plzWaitObservable.asObservable();

  public plzWait = (wait: boolean) => this.plzWaitObservable.next(wait);
}
```

### Some other component

```
constructor(private message: MessagingService) { }
somefunction() {
    this.message.plzWait(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
            this.message.plzWait(false);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Following your answer, I was finally able to get my loader to center no matter what screen size it was. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

change the position absolute of div busy to fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can use this OnLoad or during fetch infos from DB

In HTML Add following code:

```
<div id="divLoading">
<p id="loading">
    <img src="~/images/spinner.gif">
</p>
```

In CSS add following Code:

```
#divLoading {
  margin: 0px;
  display: none;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 30001;
  opacity: 0.8;}

#loading {
   position: absolute;
   color: White;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;}
```

if you want to show and hide from JS:

```
  document.getElementById('divLoading').style.display = 'none'; //Not Visible
  document.getElementById('divLoading').style.display = 'block';//Visible
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me in angular 4

by adding `style="margin:0 auto;"`

```
<mat-progress-spinner
  style="margin:0 auto;"
  *ngIf="isLoading"
  mode="indeterminate">
  </mat-progress-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: translate(50%, 50%);
```

You may try this is in my case it will work

```
<div class="position-relative">
<div class="position-absolute" style="transform: translate(50%, 50%)"> loader or anything Else</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.loader{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Phi_fenomeni.gif/50px-Phi_fenomeni.gif') 
              50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```