# How to center image in the specific div according to current viewport position?

Tags: ajax, css, jquery

I am trying create nice animation during loading content using ajax. I want to use display icon during reloading div with "Content", however I can't figured out is it possible to do that only with CSS.

Icon should:

1. horizontally always in the center of div with "Content"
2. vertically always in the center of "visible part of content"
3. should stay during whole animation in the vertically center of "visible part of content" during slide animation which hides Menu.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If vertical centering according to "visible part of content" is not possible, it would be ok to center image according to viewport of the browser.

**[EDIT]**:

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QWB9x/74/ and the part which probably should be changed:

```
.loading #img_loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works best for me :)

```
function loadNewContent(){
 $(".loaderCont").removeClass("loading")
}

$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#hide_button").on("click", function () {
      $(this).closest(".bottom").toggleClass("left_hided");
      $(".loaderCont").toggleClass("left_hided2");
 });

 $("#filter1,#filter2,#filter3,#filter4").on("click", function() {
     $(".loaderCont").addClass("loading");
     setTimeout(loadNewContent, 2000);
 });
});
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: Green;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
     height: 100px;
}
.left {
    background-color: Red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.left_hided .left{
    margin-left: -85px;
}
.right {
    background: Aqua url("http://i.imgur.com/ifyW4z8.png") 50% repeat-y;
    width: calc(100% - 140px);
    float: right;
}

.left_hided .right{
     width: calc(100% - 55px);
}

input{
    float:right;
}

.loaderCont {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 140px);
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.left_hided2 {
     width: calc(100% - 55px);
}

#loader {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif) no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - 16px);
    left: calc(50% - 16px);
    display: block;
     height: 32px;
     width: 32px;
}

.loading {
    z-index: 9001;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRwzr/1/

Answer (score 0):

For this to work to your requirements you will need to use JavaScript to determine where the loading image needs to be placed over the visible part using a fixed position div and then reposition it when the user resizes the window or scrolls the window so it is always in the desired position.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrolling();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   scrolling(); 
});

scrolling();

function scrolling() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offsetTop = $('#thediv')[0].offsetTop;
    var offsetHeight = $('#thediv')[0].offsetHeight;

    var offsetWidth = $('#thediv')[0].offsetWidth;

    var top = offsetTop - scrollTop;
    top = top < 0 ? 0 : top;

    var bottom = (scrollTop + windowHeight) - (offsetHeight + offsetTop);
    bottom = bottom < 0 ? 0 : bottom;

    $('.image').css('top', top);
    $('.image').css('bottom', bottom);
    $('.image').css('width', offsetWidth);
}
```

Please note that if you change the width of the div you will always need to call the `scrolling()` function so that it can recalculate the position.

I also added the loading image as a background image to the fixed div so that we can use CSS to centre it.

```
.image {
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QWB9x/89/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do so much of scripting to assign it a position. You can do it with simple css.

Just make the loader relative to its parent. Assign a height and width and do the following css part.

```css
.loader{
    position: relative;
    top: -half of the height;
    left: -half of the width;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

works with every device

Answer (score -2):

use z-index example:-

```
 <div style="z-index:100;">loading image</div>
```

Comment: that part is obvious ;) the question is how to use position:[fixed/absolute/relative], top, left, margins etc...

Answer (score -2):

```
.loading #img_loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% + 55px);
    display: block;
}
```

The above will solve the half of the problem, you need to update the left dynamically with javascript.

Comment: this will place loadingImage in the center of the screen, but not in the center of the div. Please see my fiddle, which I added to the question.

Comment: aahh I totally misunderstood the question.. You can do that only with javascript by calculating the visible area.. and positioning the image.. Let me edit the answer..